# Error in c++ template Snippet

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I hae written the following code:

```
class Object
{
   public:
   Object()
   {}
};

template <class T>
class Reg : public Object
{
    T val,val_new;
    public:
    Reg(T initval)
    {
    super( );
    val=initval;
    } 
};
```

The error in the code is

```
t.cpp: In constructor 'Reg<T>::Reg(T)':
Line 15: error: there are no arguments to 'super' that depend on a template parameter,
so a declaration of 'super' must be available
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

How can i eliminate the error?

Comment: What is `super`? Where is it defined? (Do you usually code in Java?)

Comment: There is no super in C++ as it allow multiple inheritance

Comment: VC++ has `__super` keyword for accessing base class (if there's no ambiguity). Other compilers may also have similar keyword. Yes, that's not standard.

Comment: I was not able to add comment(some problem in browser). Super is to call the constructor of parent class.yeah i normally work in java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Object
{
public:
   Object() {}
};

template <class T>
class Reg : public Object
{
    T val,val_new;
public:
    Reg(T const& initval)
        : val( initval )
    {} 
};
```

There is no `super` in standard C++. Some compilers offer it as a language extension, but in standard C++ if you want a generic name for “the” base class, then you have to `typedef` it. For example, in class `Reg` you can `typedef Object Base;`.

The construction `: val( initval )` is a *constructor initializer list*, where essentially you call constructors of members and base classes, avoiding default construction.

Finally, the `const&`, *passing by reference*, avoids time-consuming and memory-consuming copying of the actual argument; it's another thing that's different in C++ (compared to Java, which I’m assuming that you’re coming from).

Answer (score 2):

```
class Object
{
   public:
   Object()
   {}
};

template <class T>
class Reg : public Object
{
    T val,val_new;
    public:
    Reg(T initval) : Object() // initializer list
    {
    val=initval;
    } 
};
```

Comment: Might as well initialize `val` in the initializer list too while you're at it.